# Não estou conseguindo ver qual argumento devo usar para fazer este trabalho

Tags: c#

```
public class RetornoBO
{
    List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> OK = new List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem>();
    Dictionary<string, int> retorno = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Dictionary<string, int> baixas = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void RetornarPorImgBO(int idEmpresa, List<String> lista)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count(); i++)
            {
                var nomeImag = ValidarNomeImag(lista[i]);

                if (nomeImag != null)
                {
                    if (BaixadoNRetornado.Any(b => b.Numero_Auto == nomeImag.Numero_Auto && b.Tipo_Notificacao == nomeImag.Tipo_Notificacao))
                    {
                     OK.Add(?);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        retorno.Add(?);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clog.ArquivoLog("ImportarArquivo()", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private RetornoRomaneioPostagem ValidarNomeImag(String arquivo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (arquivo.Length == 16)
            {
                var retorno = new RetornoRomaneioPostagem();

                retorno.Tipo_Notificacao = Convert.ToInt32(arquivo.Substring(10, 1));
                retorno.Numero_Auto = String.Format("D{0}", arquivo.Substring(1, 9));

                return retorno;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clog.ArquivoLog("ImportarArquivo()", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> BaixadoNRetornado(List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> baixasNRetornadas)
    {
        try
        {
            List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> nRetorndasBaixadas = new List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem>();

            var retornoRPostagem = new RetornoRomaneioPostagem();

            if (baixasNRetornadas.Where(b => b.Numero_Auto == retornoRPostagem.Numero_Auto && b.Tipo_Notificacao == retornoRPostagem.Tipo_Notificacao).Any())
            {
                nRetorndasBaixadas.Add(retornoRPostagem);

                return nRetorndasBaixadas;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clog.ArquivoLog("ImportarArquivo()", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> NBaixaCRomaneio(List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> nBaixaCRomaneio)
    {
        try
        {
            List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> cRomaneioNBaixadas = new List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem>();

            var retornoRPost = new RetornoRomaneioPostagem();

            if (nBaixaCRomaneio.Where(c => c.Numero_Auto == retornoRPost.Numero_Auto && c.Tipo_Notificacao == retornoRPost.Tipo_Notificacao).Count() == 0)
            {
                cRomaneioNBaixadas.Add(retornoRPost);

                return cRomaneioNBaixadas;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clog.ArquivoLog("ImportarArquivo()", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: E qual é a sua pergunta? Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Qual é o problema? Além de capturar uma exceção genérica e relançar a exceção?

Comment: Também não consigo ver, mas eu falaria que não é viável.

Comment: Eu preciso fazer um if pra BaixasNRetornado dentro do if já existente, mas não estou conseguindo. Por isso tentei fazer uma variável mas esta pedindo um argumento que não consigo colocar

Comment: Pelo que parece, ele espera um `List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem>`. Cria uma lista dessa ou pega de algum lugar do seu código, se existir.

Comment: Mas precisamos saber onde está o erro e qual é ele. Sem informações relevantes não tem como responder. Vou chutar uma possibilidade, mude o `if` para: `(baixasNRetornadas.Any(b => b.Numero_Auto == retornoRPostagem.Numero_Auto && b.Tipo_Notificacao == retornoRPostagem.Tipo_Notificacao)`

Comment: Todas as coisas que eu já tentei da com argumento invalido ou que o método não existe no contexto.

Comment: Se você não passar informações completas sobre o erro, ninguém vai conseguir ajudar. Não tem como nós adivinharmos o problema sem uma descrição completa dele. Copie e cole na pergunta o que é apresentado. Se mostrar um número de linha, informe que linhas do seu código corresponde a esta linha para podermos identificar melhor. Lembre-se que não estamos vendo o mesmo que você no seu VS.

Comment: O que eu quero fazer e verificar se o numero_auto e o tipo_notificação do nomeImag existem dentro do BaixadoNRetornado

Comment: Amanda, Edite sua pergunta colocando apenas o método em que ocorre o erro. Tem diversos IF's em sua pergunta, não há como saber com clareza a qual você está se referindo.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi o problema a solução seria esta:

```
private List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> BaixadoNRetornado(List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem> baixasNRetornadas) {
    try {
        var nRetorndasBaixadas = new List<RetornoRomaneioPostagem>();
        var retornoRPostagem = new RetornoRomaneioPostagem();
        if (baixasNRetornadas.Any(b => b.Numero_Auto == retornoRPostagem.Numero_Auto && b.Tipo_Notificacao == retornoRPostagem.Tipo_Notificacao)) {
            nRetorndasBaixadas.Add(retornoRPostagem);
            return nRetorndasBaixadas;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        clog.ArquivoLog("Alguma informação relevante aqui, não qualquer coisa", ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/BusinessRule.cs).

Tenho sérias dúvidas se deveria fazer o código assim, não parece fazer sentido. Os dois métodos parecem fazer coisas desnecessárias.

Note que além do problema que havia no código melhorei o tratamento da exceção. Tenho minhas dúvidas se esse tratamento deveria estar aí mas não posso afirmar nada sem ver toda aplicação. Recomendo repensar na forma como lida com as exceções. Tem várias respostas minhas aqui no *site* falando sobre isto.

Se há mais algum problema, principalmente de lógica não tem como saber sem ter mais detalhes.

Pelo menos isto ajudava antes da edição da pergunta. Eu poderia ajudar mais se soubesse qual e onde exatamente está o erro mas não consegui obter esta informação apesar de inúmeras tentativas.